# ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, min

I'm current coding a highway traffic model. On the deciding the distance between the front car, I'm stuck at min(). It somehow an empty sequence.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> [93, 72, 55]
>
> File "C:/Users/Try Arie/PycharmProjects/traffic_model/traffic.py", line 44, in
>
> 55
>
> []
>
> d = min(dlist)
>
> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

I checked the value of distance list. It should be inside and using min(), I will assign the lowest value to d. But it doesn't

```
class car:

    def __init__(self, no, x, v):
        self.no = no
        self.x = x
        self.v = v


for i in range(N):
    cars.append(car(i+1, randint(0, 100), 0))

for i in range(N):

    dlist = []

    for j in range(N):
        if cars[j].x > cars[i].x:
            dlist.append(cars[j].x)

    print(dlist)

    d = min(dlist)

    print(d)
```

I want value d 55, so then I can use it for my next code

Comment: If anyone wondering the x (position) of each car, here: 53, 93, 1, 38, 47, 24, 34, 72, 55, 20

Comment: somehow `if cars[j].x > cars[i].x:` this condition is not met and the dlist remains empty which cause the error

Comment: what does `print(dlist)` show?

Comment: print(dlist) print all value in the list. It's [93, 72, 55].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dlist` will by empty for the `i` for which `cars[i].x` has the biggest value. For this `i` the test `cars[j].x > cars[i].x` will never be true, hence you will never append anything to `dlist`.

As you can see in your output that exactly this happens: In the first iteration over `i` you find all cars with `x` larger than 53: `[93, 72, 55]` and you also print 55. In the next iteration you find all cars with `x` larger than 93. There is no such car, hence you get an empty dllist `[]` and then `min` raises an exception.

You will either have to treat the special case of empty explicitly or use `>=` instead of `>` in your test.

And btw, wouldn't it be faster/easier to just sort the cars by `x`? Then at position `k` in the sorted list you have the minimum car among all the cars that have an `x` larger than or equal to `cars[k].x`.